# Begonia (angel wing) has scraggly leaves

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, begonia

My begonia has developed the weirdest leaf symptoms over the last few months and I can’t figure out what’s wrong.

The stems are strong and the growth rate seems normal, but nearly every leaf developed delicate brown spots, scraggly torn edges, or they simply drop without warning. Often, the healthier looking leaves drop, but the scraggly ones stay on. Baby leaves develop symptoms almost immediately.

I thought it might be bugs of some sort, or root rot, but I’ve found no evidence of either. No other plants nearby have bugs or symptoms.

The plant is in a terra-cotta pot with good drainage. She gets a many (4-6) hours of indirect south facing sunlight. I water about once per week, unless she’s looking extra droopy. (It’s droopy I’m the photos, today is watering day though. It is also an indoor plant, despite being outside in the pictures. I took it outside just briefly for other purposes.)

Any ideas of what’s wrong? She used to be so shiny and vibrant! Begonias are one of my favorite plants, but I’m stumped!

[image: begonia leaf]
[image: full plant]
[image: leaf two]
[image: back of leaf]